# Cant get the wifi to work on Macbook air early 2015 (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: wireless, 15.10, macbook-air

As i have low internal memory only 128 GB. so i do not wish to install in my hard drive. Instead i wish to use it on my flash drive itself with persistence. My problem is i cant get the wifi to work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution to my problem.

To get the wifi driver working on Macbook air (early 2015)

**1st step**
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)

**2nd Step**
Download the latest driver from below link.
http://ftp.wa.co.za/pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/

**Note** : Choose the latest one. and If you are using the 32bit version download the 32bit version of driver. and for 64bit download that one. For me i was trying to get the wifi working in kali linux, so for me i could not get the kali linux 64 to boot into my macbook air so i choosed 32bit, as it dosent matter for me eitherway because i got the base model which has only 4GB of ram.

3rd Step
sudo dpkg -i (the driver name)

**note**: for me "*bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.3_i386.deb*" this was the latest driver and it worked. 
so for me it is 
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.3_i386.deb

and tadaa it works.. (well for me it worked)

you could try with sudo service network-manager restart
and try again.

```
***This tutorial should work for all ubuntu and debian based Distros.***
```